# Android AudioManager getStreamVolume isRestricted mode

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am attempting a small android application with exoplayer 2.x, while debugging in the console this message keeps repeating

```
D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
```

I have not been able to find anything related to this. Anybody knows what is this and how to get rid of it? and will it affect performance as it keeps printing.

Comment: Is a issue with admob